# how to create a php page that auto change the value of coloumn after 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

i have a Mysql server, and my table have a column name 'status'. i want to create a page that check every entry , if entry 'status'  value is 0 then make it false after 24 hours. How can i create this page. Please help . I am php beginner . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a page that change that 'status' field, without any time dependency. [For example](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-to-MySQL-Using-PHP)
2. Run that page with [CRON](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/) every 24 hours.